# How for element of one array assign another array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a variable T, which contains 4 characteristics of one pixel of the image.

```py
T = [ph, pv, pd, pe]
```

I also created a matrix that will duplicate the size of the image and each of its elements will correspond to the size of the image.

```py
Matrix = []
```

But when I began to assign the characteristic T to the elements of the matrix, an error occurred.

```py
for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
#finding elements of T
#...
        T = [ph, pv, pd, pe]
        Matrix[i, j] = T

ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Aydar/PycharmProjects/Plan_main/main.py", line 245, in <module>
    Matrix[i, j] = T
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

It must be like:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf9N0.jpg]

Comment: I'm wondering if [```itertools.product()```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) would be a more Pythonic and efficient way to iterate over ```a(i, j)``` pairs. Something like this: ```for i, j in itertools.product(range(height), range(width)):```.

Comment: You should probably use NumPy for this...

Answer (score 0):

If `Martix` is a list of lists, use this instead:

```
Matrix[i][j] = T
```